# How to send/get parsed console output file in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have used log parser plug-in to find out the errors and warning and able to see it into console log(parsed) section over Jenkins. Now I have to send those parsed log file to recipient user. To send mail them,  I can editable email notification in Jenkins with attached build log, but that is not sending parsed output of it which highlights errors and warning?

However, instead of this, is there also a way that I can able to send only errors and warning files to them?

I am also try to achieve it through groovy script but I am not able to fetch errorLinksFile/htmlLogFile which generates it in runtime.

any other approach also helpful for me to get errorLinks file?

Comment: You should review the comments in this post on [Build Failure Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=74056022#content/view/74056022)